# Can't find link element with driver.find_element_by_xpath for Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the first link on the Google patents search page.

I used this to get to the link:

```
        result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='link']")
        result.click()
        time.sleep(10)
```

However it does not find the link.

The HTML is:

```
<a id="link" href="/patent/US7610070B2/en?assignee=Allegheny&amp;page=1" class="style-scope state-modifier">
```

Followed by:

```
<h3 class="style-scope search-result-item"><raw-html class="style-scope search-result-item">
<span id="htmlContent" class="style-scope raw-html" style="display: inline;"> Dynamically configured antenna for multiple frequencies and bandwidths</span>
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the search may return more than one result with the same id ("link"), try something like this:

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='link'][1]")
```

Note that the `[1]` select only the first element matching the condition (`@id='link'`).